# Invalid Argument error:Load a (frozen) Tensorflow model into memory (While testing the model on local machine)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection-api

- I am using the tensorflow object detection API.
- I have performed the training on the remote server GPU and saved the frozen model and checkpoints.
- After that i took that frozen model along with checkpoints and copied to my local machine and then performed the testing on my test data using the the script "object_detection_tutorial.ipnyb"

When i run this cell "Load a (frozen) Tensorflow model into memory", it gives the `invalid argument` error.

Can you please explain what is the issue while running the save model on my local machine ? Is it necessary that that the training and testing should be on same machine? I was encountered with the following error:

> InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py
>   in import_graph_def(graph_def, input_map, return_elements, name,
>   op_dict, producer_op_list)
>       417         results = c_api.TF_GraphImportGraphDefWithResults(
>   --> 418             graph._c_graph, serialized, options)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
>       419         results = c_api_util.ScopedTFImportGraphDefResults(results)
>
> InvalidArgumentError: NodeDef mentions attr 'T' not in
>   Op
>   selected_indices:int32>; NodeDef: {{node
>   Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/non_max_suppression/NonMaxSuppressionV3}}
>   = NonMaxSuppressionV3[T=DT_FLOAT](Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/unstack,
>   Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/Reshape,
>   Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/Minimum,
>   Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/non_max_suppression/iou_threshold,
>   Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/non_max_suppression/score_threshold).
>   (Check whether your GraphDef-interpreting binary is up to date with
>   your GraphDef-generating binary.).
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         5     serialized_graph = fid.read()
>         6     od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
>   ----> 7     tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py
>   in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
>       486                 'in a future version' if date is None else ('after %s' % date),
>       487                 instructions)
>   --> 488       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>       489     return tf_decorator.make_decorator(func, new_func, 'deprecated',
>       490                                        _add_deprecated_arg_notice_to_docstring(
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py
>   in import_graph_def(graph_def, input_map, return_elements, name,
>   op_dict, producer_op_list)
>       420       except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:
>       421         # Convert to ValueError for backwards compatibility.
>   --> 422         raise ValueError(str(e))
>       423 
>       424     # Create _DefinedFunctions for any imported functions.
>
> ValueError: NodeDef mentions attr 'T' not in
>   Op
>   selected_indices:int32>; NodeDef: {{node
>   Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/non_max_suppression/NonMaxSuppressionV3}}
>   = NonMaxSuppressionV3[T=DT_FLOAT](Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/unstack,
>   Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/Reshape,
>   Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/Minimum,
>   Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/non_max_suppression/iou_threshold,
>   Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/non_max_suppression/score_threshold).
>   (Check whether your GraphDef-interpreting binary is up to date with
>   your GraphDef-generating binary.).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. The solution for me was to take my GPU training files from TF1.9 and move them to my local TF1.5 CPU environment (which doesn't support AVX instructions). I then created the frozen model on the local environment from the training files and was successfully able to use it.